# output an array using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
    $data = $row['name'];
 }
```

I fetch all the data with the column name **"name"** in database. How can I output it like this?

```
 ["John", "Doe", "Deer"]
```

Comment: do you wants to get output as array?

Comment: yes. so that it will be readable in my jquery code.

Comment: If you mean how to form an array like that one of what you get from database, `$data = []; while(....) { $data[] = $row['name'];`

Comment: Are you asking how you output the data in the format you specified or how you atore multiple values in $data?

Answer (score 4):

You have to make $data as array type variable.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
   $data[] = $row['name'];
 }

 print_r($data); // required output
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
   $data[] = $row['name'];
 }

 print_r($data); // output key wise display like
 Array ( [0] => John [1] => Doe  ) etc.
```

But output as you suggestion then just add `json_encode()`

```
print_r(json_encode($data)); // output like
["John", "Doe", "Deer"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  $data = $row['name'];
}
echo json_encode($data); // or you can use print_r for debugging.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use json_encode() method to your array to be accepted in your jquery. Rearrange the code like following..

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
   $data[] = $row['name'];
}

$new_array = json_encode($data);
echo $new_array;   // use 'echo' to print. The json_encode() convert $data array to string.
```